# How to join two tables in PostgreSQL with similar columns and leave unmatching fields NULL or untouched

Tags: postgresql, left-join, union

I have a main table Grade. I already joined this table with the Class table. Now I want to join another table, Instructor.

Grade

| ClassID | AverageGrade |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A |
| 2 | B |
| 3 | B+ |

Class

| ID | Class |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Math |
| 2 | English |
| 3 | History |
| 4 | Spanish |
| 5 | Science |

Instructor

| Class | Instructor |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Alice |
| 2 | Bob |
| 4 | Charlie |

The current query I have is

```
select * from Grade left join Class on Grade.ClassID = Class.ID
```

Is there any way I can left join `Instructor` on top of this query, such that my table has the following?

| ID | Class | AverageGrade | Instructor |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Math | A | Alice |
| 2 | English | B | Bob |
| 3 | History | B+ |  |
| 4 | Spanish |  | Charlie |

Not including 5-Science as it has neither a grade nor an instructor.

Due to other reasons, I have to join Grade first.

Thanks!

Comment: You write you have to join Grade first - you mean it must be the first table in "from" part for some reason?
Also do I understand you correctly - you want to see only classes that have either grade or instructor of both. If none is available - class is not to be shown?

Comment: @JuliusTuskenis Sorry it wasn't clear. But yes to both questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can not LEFT JOIN Instructor on top of the query you have, because the first table (Grade) limits the amount of records you get in result when using left joins. You can't have NULL from Grade table in result if you are only left join'ing.

**Other options:**

Having to start from Grade limits some most obvious options, but I still can think of two:

1. Using right join to join class and then joining instructor. This way I need to filter out classes without instructors and grades in WHERE part:

```
select 
  Class.ID,
  Class.Class,
  Grade.AverageGrade,
  Instructor.Instructor
from 
  Grade
  right join Class on Grade.ClassID = Class.ID
  left join Instructor on Class.ID = Instructor.Class
where 
  Grade.AverageGrade is not null
  or instructor.Instructor is not null
```

2. Using full join of grade and instructor returns the records I need, so no filtering is needed later, but the class should be joined using id from either grade or instructor as one of them may be NULL.

```
select 
  Class.ID,
  Class.Class,
  Grade.AverageGrade,
  Instructor.Instructor
from 
  Grade
  full join Instructor on Grade.ClassID = Instructor.Class
  join Class on coalesce(Grade.ClassID, Instructor.class) = Class.ID
```

They both return the same result.

Comment: Thanks so much! I used the full join option. Although it seems like when I added the condition for Instructor during full join e.g. `full join Instructor on Grade.ClassID = Instructor.Class and Instructor.ID < 5`, the `<5` condition did not work. It still full joined all the instructors no matter what the ID is. I had to add this condition in the where clause. Or when full join'ing, I full joined `select * from Instructor where Instructor.ID < 5`. Both work, but just curious why I can't have it in the full join condition.

Comment: @cxc the Instructor table as you defined in the question hasn't ID. Is it new column, or do you mean Instructor.Class ?
Anyway - to answer your question, the conditions of the full join describes how the records from both tables will be joined. If the condition is false - the records still appears in the result with nulls in other table fields.